# What does it mean for something to be "more" Gaussian?

Tags: information-theory

I'm currently reading [this paper](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam032/98032172.pdf) on information theory and the brain. Within the text (p. 16) they say:

> It is important to note that the above expression [the mutual
>   information between a signal and it's noise-corrupted version] is only
>   valid when both the signal and the noise are Gaussian. While this is
>   often a reasonable and testable assumption, because of the central
>   limit theorem, it is only an estimate and can underestimate the
>   information (if the signal is more Gaussian than the noise) or
>   overestimate the information (if the noise is more Gaussian than the
>   signal).

What does it mean for something to be "more" Gaussian? How can this be measured?

Comment: Without reading anything else I can guess it means "of higher variance" but that's just a blind shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "more gaussian" thing here alludes to the property that, for a fixed variance, the gaussian density is that which maximizes the entropy. Hence, one could say that a random variable is more or less gaussian dependending on how high its entropy is, relative to the maximum.

Let $Y=X+Z$ where $Z$ is the noise, independent of $X$

Then $I(X;Y) = H(Y)-H(Y|X) = H(X+Z)-H(Z)$

Suppose that the signals have 0 mean and fixed variances $\sigma_X^2$ , $\sigma_Z^2$ ($\sigma_Y^2=\sigma_X^2+ \sigma_Z^2$)

Then $H(Z) \le  \frac{1}{2} \log \sigma_Z^2 + \alpha $ and $H(X+Z) \le \frac{1}{2} \log \sigma_Y^2 + \alpha$ with the equalities attained if $X$ and $Z$ (and hence $Y$) are gaussian  (here $\alpha = \frac{1}{2} \log 2 \pi e$)

In the gaussian case, then, we get the familiar

$$I(X;Y) = \frac{1}{2} \log \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{\sigma_Z^2} = \frac{1}{2} \log \left( 1 + \frac{\sigma_X^2}{\sigma_Z^2} \right)$$

Now, if $Z$ is gaussian but $X$ is not, then $Y$ is neither gaussian, and the second inequality is strict. Hence, the information is strictly less than the above.

In other cases ($Z$ not gaussian), things are a little more complicated, but the idea is the same.